Is .strokeStyle of the canvas API a method which makes itself global?
I am curious on the curious behaviour of js, in particular with this method .strokeStyle which usually is used to change the color of a stroke on a HTML canvas. It seems to me quite peculiar, for exmaple if I use 2 functions such as in this snippet (to draw an 'L')-


const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function first() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
};

function second() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(20, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
};

first();
second();
<h1>HTML5 Canvas</h1>
<h2>The stroke() Method</h2>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey">
</canvas>



One might expect that when the second() is executed, it's stroke color will be Black (since this is the default). However, this does not happen and the stroke color is Red. This seems strange to me since coming from the land of functional programming, I see function as isolated, independent units of code. Am I doing something wrong? if not, then is there a way to contain it's global effects?

Both of your functions access the same object, const ctx = c.getContext("2d"); - after you set the stroke color for this 2D context once, it remains set.

In non-functional programming, it's very common for objects to have mutable state. This simplifies the programming quite a bit but is more prone to bugs. Immutability: safer, but more hoops to jump through to make the code work. Mutability: less safe, but easier to work with.  It's a language design tradeoff.

The canvas context acts like a JS object (with lots of getter setter magics, but here it doesn't matter). Just like if you modified a plain object in first, its state would expose the modifications in second.


const ctx = { strokeStyle: "black" } // plain object

function first() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  console.log("in first", ctx.strokeStyle);
};

function second() {
  console.log("in second", ctx.strokeStyle);
};

first();
second();




I hope this helps. So... you need to use save and restore methods.
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
function first() {
  ctx.save(); // Save the current state
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // Restore the previous state
}

function second() {
  ctx.save(); // Save the current state
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; // Explicitly set the stroke style to black
  ctx.moveTo(20, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // Restore the previous state
}

first();
second();

Here is the working example and here is more info about save and reset methods.

Why do I have to explicitly set the stroke color (since black is already default) or save and restore states (since the funcs are not in a class)

When you execute first(), it sets ctx.strokeStyle to "red", and this setting persists. So, when you call second(), unless you explicitly change ctx.strokeStyle, the line drawn will also be red, because the canvas context's stroke color remains the same across both function calls. You need to explicitly set the strokeStyle or use save() and restore() methods because the canvas context maintains a global state that persists across function calls

@The_frontender because you already overwrote that default, by assigning a new value via ctx.strokeStyle = "red"; Both your functions operate on the same ctx object.
